# Having trouble inporting files via download link into google colab in order to train an A.I

Tags: google-colaboratory, file-management, getfiles

Files are not downloading into the colab when i use my own download link. i cant figure out why its not working. I also went looking on different webistes about how to manage files in colab but nothing is working, i have very little experience with code and was wondering if anyone would be bale to solve my issue as i assume its probably an easy issue to solve

Here is the full code:

```
pip install tensorflow numpy matplotlib

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2, ResNet50, InceptionV3 # try to use them and see which is better
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_file
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
import pathlib
import numpy as np

batch_size = 5
# 7 artists (currently)
num_classes = 7
# training for 10 epochs
epochs = 10
# size of each image
IMAGE_SHAPE = (1000, 1000, 3)

def load_data():
    """This function downloads, extracts, loads, normalizes and one-hot encodes Flower Photos dataset"""
    # download the dataset and extract it
    #data_dir = get_file(origin='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6',  # original file https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz
    data_url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6"
    data_dir = get_file(origin=data_url, fname="data_set", untar=True)                                          # original fname = flower_photos
    data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
    # count how many images are there
    image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
    print("Number of images:", image_count)
    # get all classes for this dataset (types of flowers) excluding LICENSE file
    CLASS_NAMES = np.array([item.name for item in data_dir.glob('*') if item.name != "LICENSE.txt"])
    # roses = list(data_dir.glob('roses/*'))
    # 20% validation set 80% training set
    image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255, validation_split=0.2)
    # make the training dataset generator
    train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=str(data_dir), batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        classes=list(CLASS_NAMES), target_size=(IMAGE_SHAPE[0], IMAGE_SHAPE[1]),
                                                        shuffle=True, subset="training")
    # make the validation dataset generator
    test_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=str(data_dir), batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        classes=list(CLASS_NAMES), target_size=(IMAGE_SHAPE[0], IMAGE_SHAPE[1]),
                                                        shuffle=True, subset="validation")
    return train_data_gen, test_data_gen, CLASS_NAMES


def create_model(input_shape):
    # load MobileNetV2
    model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=input_shape)
    # remove the last fully connected layer
    model.layers.pop()
    # freeze all the weights of the model except the last 4 layers
    for layer in model.layers[:-4]:
        layer.trainable = False
    # construct our own fully connected layer for classification
    output = Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax")
    # connect that dense layer to the model
    output = output(model.layers[-1].output)
    model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=output)
    # print the summary of the model architecture
    model.summary()
    # training the model using adam optimizer
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # load the data generators
    train_generator, validation_generator, class_names = load_data()
    # constructs the model
    model = create_model(input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE)
    # model name
    model_name = "MobileNetV2_finetune_last5"
    # some nice callbacks
    tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join("logs", model_name))
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join("results", f"{model_name}" + "-loss-{val_loss:.2f}.h5"),
                                save_best_only=True,
                                verbose=1)
    # make sure results folder exist
    if not os.path.isdir("results"):
        os.mkdir("results")
    # count number of steps per epoch
    training_steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(train_generator.samples / batch_size)
    validation_steps_per_epoch = np.ceil(validation_generator.samples / batch_size)
    # train using the generators
    model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=training_steps_per_epoch,
                        validation_data=validation_generator, validation_steps=validation_steps_per_epoch,
                        epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[tensorboard, checkpoint])

which then outputs this error when its run:

Downloading data from https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6
   8192/Unknown - 0s 0us/stepNumber of images: 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-102c652a5bdf> in <cell line: 1>()
      1 if __name__ == "__main__":
      2     # load the data generators
----> 3     train_generator, validation_generator, class_names = load_data()
      4     # constructs the model
      5     model = create_model(input_shape=IMAGE_SHAPE)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/preprocessing/image.py in __init__(self, directory, image_data_generator, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, follow_links, subset, interpolation, keep_aspect_ratio, dtype)
 561         if not classes:
    562             classes = []
--> 563             for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
    564                 if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, subdir)):
    565                     classes.append(subdir)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.keras/datasets/data_set
```

i tried replacing the folder, making a new download link, changing the path etc. but it still wont work

Comment: See the *minimal* part of the [mcve] guidance. If the question is just about how to find/load files on Colab, it's not really an AI question. If you scale the question down to where the problem actually is, it helps you debug but also means more people can help without needing to have TF available

Answer (score 0):

The actual download URL seems to be https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6. I can see it working via `

```
wget -O 18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6.zip --no-check-certificate -r 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6'

WARNING: combining -O with -r or -p will mean that all downloaded content
will be placed in the single file you specified.

--2023-09-24 09:05:56--  https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6
Resolving drive.google.com (drive.google.com)... 172.217.164.110
Connecting to drive.google.com (drive.google.com)|172.217.164.110|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6.zip’

18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQ     [ <=>                                                   ]   2.22K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2023-09-24 09:05:56 (72.4 MB/s) - ‘18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6.zip’ saved [2277]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2023-09-24 09:05:56--  https://drive.google.com/robots.txt
Reusing existing connection to drive.google.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6.zip’

18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQ     [ <=>                                                   ]     570  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2023-09-24 09:05:56 (19.4 MB/s) - ‘18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6.zip’ saved [570]

--2023-09-24 09:05:56--  https://drive.google.com/open?id=18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6
Reusing existing connection to drive.google.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6/view?usp=drive_open [following]
--2023-09-24 09:05:56--  https://drive.google.com/file/d/18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6/view?usp=drive_open
Reusing existing connection to drive.google.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6.zip’

18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQ     [ <=>                                                   ]  80.25K  --.-KB/s    in 0.09s

2023-09-24 09:05:57 (866 KB/s) - ‘18FLNpct5RZlf4BZBpAaM6n7bzoQmSQR6.zip’ saved [82171]

FINISHED --2023-09-24 09:05:57--
Total wall clock time: 1.1s
Downloaded: 3 files, 83K in 0.09s (895 KB/s)
```

`